# Why is Excel serial date-time to NSDate conversion two days, one hour and 40 minutes ahead?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I'm converting dates from an Excel spreadsheet to NSDate's, but for some reason they always come out two days ahead: Sundays come out as Tuesdays, etc.

My conversion method is based on the following info from [cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm):

> Excel stores dates and times as a number representing the number of
>   days since 1900-Jan-0, plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day:
>   ddddd.tttttt . This is called a serial date, or serial date-time. 
>   (...) The integer portion of the number, ddddd, represents the number
>   of days since 1900-Jan-0.  (...) The fractional portion of the number,
>   ttttt, represents the fractional portion of a 24 hour day.  For
>   example, 6:00 AM is stored as 0.25, or 25% of a 24 hour day. 
>   Similarly, 6PM is stored at 0.75,  or 75% percent of a 24 hour day.

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromExcelSerialDate:(double)serialdate
{
    if (serialdate == 0)
        return nil;

    NSTimeInterval theTimeInterval;
    NSInteger numberOfSecondsInOneDay = 86400;

    double integral;
    double fractional = modf(serialdate, &integral);

    NSLog(@"%@ %@ \r serialdate = %f, integral = %f, fractional = %f",
          [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),
          serialdate, integral, fractional);

    theTimeInterval = integral * numberOfSecondsInOneDay; //number of days
    if (fractional > 0) {
        theTimeInterval += numberOfSecondsInOneDay / fractional; //portion of one day
    }

    NSCalendar *nl_gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSTimeZone *nl_timezone = [[NSTimeZone alloc] initWithName:@"Europe/Amsterdam"];
    [nl_gregorianCalendar setTimeZone:nl_timezone];

    NSDateComponents *excelBaseDateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [excelBaseDateComps setMonth:1];
    [excelBaseDateComps setDay:1];
    [excelBaseDateComps setHour:00];
    [excelBaseDateComps setMinute:00];
    [excelBaseDateComps setTimeZone:nl_timezone];
    [excelBaseDateComps setYear:1900];
    NSDate *excelBaseDate = [nl_gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:excelBaseDateComps];

    NSDate *inputDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:theTimeInterval sinceDate:excelBaseDate];

    NSLog(@"%@ %@ \r serialdate %f, theTimeInterval = %f \r inputDate = %@",
          [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),
          serialdate, theTimeInterval,
          [self.nl_dateFormatter stringFromDate:inputDate]);

    return inputDate;
}
```

The spreadsheet was produced in the Netherlands, presumably on a Dutch version of Microsoft Excel.
Spreadsheet date Sunday July 6, 2014 00:00 yields the following results:
dateFromExcelSerialDate:

> serialdate = 41826.000000, integral = 41826.000000, fractional =
>   0.000000 theTimeInterval = 3613766400.000000   inputDate = 08 jul. 2014 01:40

Similarly, Sunday July 13, 2014 00:00 yields:

> serialdate = 41833.000000, integral = 41833.000000, fractional =
>   0.000000 theTimeInterval = 3614371200.000000   inputDate = 15 jul. 2014 01:40

I can correct the output by subtracting 2 days, one hour and 40 minutes:

```
theTimeInterval -= ((60 * 60 * 24 * 2) + (60*60) + (60*40));
```

but I have no idea how robust that is.

That difference of two days made me think it had something to do with leap year corrections, so I tried to let the calendar do the calculations by adding the NSTimeInterval seconds to the excelBaseDate, like so:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
         [comps setSecond:theInterval];
         NSDate *inputDate = [nl_gregorianCalendar dateByAddingComponents:comps
         toDate:excelBaseDate
         options:0];
```

Strangely enough, that gave me dates somewhere in the 1870's. Who knows what is going on?

Comment: Can you please provide one to two reference dates as excel sees it (i.e. I want the 'excel date' (double) and the formatted date that excel considers that to be).  I can see where one of the days is going (`setDay:1` should be `setDay:0` as far as the "rules" you publish are concerned) but I cannot find the rest of the difference.

Comment: It's in the copied NSLog output above: the serial date-time for July 6, 2014 is 41826.000000, for July 13 is 41833.000000.

Comment: I replaced the reference to property self.nl_timezone with the line where I explicitly set nl_timezone to [[NSTimeZone alloc] initWithName:@"Europe/Amsterdam"]. Sorry about that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there are two things here:

1. your start date is `1900-Jan-1` but your referred description clearly says: the reference is `1900-Jan-0` – *you may add an extra day here*;
2. year 1900 was not a leap-year – *you may add an extra day here*;

I guess, this is pretty much the reason why you get two extra days every occasion.

---

Microsoft knows about that, [see more](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214326) about the topic here.

Comment: I'm somewhat perplexed at the idea of Jan 0 being an actual date, but it does work. As for adding a day because a year is not a leap year -- is there a reason for that?

Comment: unfortunately, the Excel thinks it was a leap-year(!), so probably it adds an extra day to the value when the `dddd.tttt` number is calculated. you may need to consider it in your code. Apple won't make such mistakes than Microsoft would. so... you have added an extra day, and the Excel added another extra day, that is clearly _two_ extra days.

Comment: Amazingly that's more than Microsoft-bashing: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214326. So, subtracting a day by default is safe. Now the dilemma is: should I assume that they were equally sloppy in their hours and minutes or is there some other issue, like the offset from GMT or daylight saving time.

Comment: @ElisevanLooij, we are talking about Microsoft, they are famous of making their own standard instead of using world's one... but using the percentage of 24 hours looks straightforward to me, vica-verse.

Comment: I'm 99% convinced the 1 hour 40 difference is a NSTimeZone / NSLocale issue. When I tried out the code @trojanfoe posted, the difference suddenly jumped to 2 hours, which I ascribed to trojanfoe using [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]; rather than the @"Europe/Amsterdam" timeZone I use.

Comment: Did you ever solve this 1 hour 40 difference? I have the same thing. When I use the code [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0] to set the time zone, I get exactly 6 hours off. I'm in Calgary, so currently we are 6 hours behind GMT. But if I set the Time Zone to localTimeZone or systemTimeZone, then I get 2:26 pm when I should get 4:00 pm for my date samples. I also had to set the month to 0 as well as the day in the base date.

Comment: @ElisevanLooij I'm also working the other way, trying to convert from an NSDate to an Excel serialized date so that I can write into an XLSX file.